# Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: No license for objc

Tags: macos, sonarqube

I am trying to set up Sonar qube for my XCode project on my mac.
I have done the set up and trying to execute `sonar-runner` command. I am receiving error `Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: No license for objc`
Below is stacktrace:

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------------                                    -------
Total time: 2.692s
Final Memory: 12M/301M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at                 org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: No license for objc
at com.A.A.A.B.B.A(Unknown Source)
at com.A.A.A.B.B.A(Unknown Source)
at com.A.A.A.B.H.A(Unknown Source)
at com.A.A.A.B.H.A(Unknown Source)
at com.A.A.A.B.I.B(Unknown Source)
at com.A.A.A.B.I.onSensorsPhase(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsPhaseEvent.dispatch(SensorsPhaseEvent.java:44)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsPhaseEvent.dispatch(SensorsPhaseEvent.java:27)
at org.sonar.batch.events.EventBus.doFireEvent(EventBus.java:49)
at org.sonar.batch.events.EventBus.fireEvent(EventBus.java:43)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:47)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:258)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:253)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:76)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 9 more
```

Any help?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but maybe it can't find a license for objc.

Answer (score 1):

You have apparently installed the C/C++, Objective-C plugin, *and* you have `.m` files in your project. Since the C-Family plugin registers `.m` files as belonging to the Objective-C language, and those files are included in the analysis, you're inherently trying to use functionality you don't have a license for. You'll need to do one of the following:

- obtain a license
- remove the plugin from your SonarQube instance and restart it
- remove the `.m` files from your project
- remove `.m` from the extensions mapped to Objective-C (Administration > General Settings > C / C++ / Objective-C > Objective-C > Objective-C File Suffixes) . Since `.m` is the default value; you'll have to accomplish this by filling in nonsense.

Comment: But I want to analyse my XCode project which contains .m and .h files. Modified question now.

Comment: I have referred this [link](https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c) for objective c plugin

Comment: @iAsh do you also have the commercial plugin installed? May help to give a full list of your plugins.